# Process or threads to use for the given scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, scalability, distributed-computing

I have one scenario where I am confused about using thread or process:

I have an application which talks to several other 3rd party web applications provided by different companies and pulls data from those applications. So basically my application hits api provided by those 3rd party apps, brings a lot of data and dumps them into a database.

Now several factors are significant here like - network latency, db read/write, slow / fast server at either end etc. So basically the application is heavily time and resource intensive and its performance is dependent on various factors.

Now for bringing such a huge data what can be the best way to design the application in terms of using process / threads?

I know thread has many positive sides like - fast context switching, resource sharing, light weight etc. And process is heavier than thread.

From my application's perspective, I have following requirements:

1. The database and network is to be shared among multiple process / threads.
2. Mutual exclusion must be there.
3. The application has to be crash-proof. So when a thread crashes, it doesn't impact the whole process.

So for the above scenario, suggest me what should I go with - thread in the same process or multiple processes?

Please point out if I am missing any case in my thought process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, IMHO you should not think about the solution at process and thread level.
Instead of this you should first come up with a solution without any scalability,performance and high-availability concerns.

For example as far as I understand you will consume 3rd party external services with a REST client. So you will need a http client layer.
Then most probably you will transform the incoming data to your own data structure.
Finally you will need a database layer to persist transformed data.

After you have your solution you can test it and figure out in which layer you will need performance improvements,scalability and high-availability tweaks.

Because the "huge" in the "huge data" is vague. And not only size of data but also duration needed to process that "huge data" matters also. If you need to deal with 100 GB of data in 1 day it may not be big deal but dealing with 100MB per minute can be.

So as a general optimization rule I learned so far, before doing any change for optimization and scalability you should clearly understand every piece of solution and identify problematic points. Otherwise you could spend so many unnecessary time to optimize the wrong parts and you would come up with a not scalable and overdue solution at the end.